# Symbol for $\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 0 \right\}$

Tags: notation

Is there a symbol for the following set?

$$
\left\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 0 \right\}
$$

Comment: How about $(0,\infty)$ ?

Comment: How about $\mathbb{R}^{>0} ? $

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any standard notations for denoting $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 0\}$ that don't presuppose the existence of $\mathbb{R}$. Which is a real shame, since this number system is nice enough that it deserves to stand on its own.

Comment: Duplicate of [How does one denote the set of all positive real numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/27968/856) Apropos of most of the answers, see also [Does set $\mathbb R^+$ include zero?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1706/856)

Answer (score 3):

Generally, $\mathbb{R}^+$ is used to denote the positive reals.

Comment: But what does "generally" mean? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would use $\mathbb R^+$ though some authors use this symbol for $\{x\in\mathbb R: x\geq 0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen people using $$\mathbb{R}_{>0},(0,\infty)\text{ and also }\mathbb{R}^+$$